# Measurable functions of finite measure spaces

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X;\mu )$ be a finite measure space; $f : X \to R$ be a measurable
function. Assume $\mu(f > 0) > 0$. Is it true that for every $\epsilon> 0$ there
is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\mu(0 < f < \delta) < \epsilon$?

I need a hint on how to start the solution.

Comment: Hint: A finite measure is "continuous from above" - see somewhere in the book for what that means...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there exists $c>0$ such that for every $n>0$, $\mu(0<f<1/n)\geq c$. Write $\mu(f>0) =A$.
We have $\mu(f\geq 1/n) =\mu(f>0) -\mu(0<f<1/n)\leq A-c$.

Since $(f>0)\subset \bigcup_n (f\geq 1/n)$, we deduce $\mu(f>0)\leq lim_n\mu(f\geq 1/n)\leq A-c$. This is a contradiction with the fact that $\mu(f>0) =A$.